# Java How to search a word from text file

Tags: java

edit: *Write a program to read in 100 words from a file. Then, have the user search for a word until they enter 'quit'.
The program will read in up to 100 words from a file. The file may or may not contain 100 words but the array should hold up to 100 (if the list does not contain enough words, fill the rest of the array with empty strings).
After the file is read in, the program will prompt the user for a search string. The program will then search for the string and tell the user if the word was found or not. The program will continue to get search strings from the user until the user enters 'quit'*

Hello I need help write a program to find a word from text file

the result should look like:

Enter a word to search for: taco

Word 'taco' was found.

Enter a word to search for: asd

Word 'asd' was NOT found.

and when user enter the word "quit" the program will quit

below is what I have so far and need help to complete

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class project2 {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    String[] list;
    String  search;

    list = load_list( "words.txt" );
    search = prompt_user( "\nEnter a word to search for: " );
    while ( ! search.equals( "quit" ) ) {
      System.out.println( "Word '" + search + "' was" +
            ( ( find_word( search, list ) ) ? "" : " NOT" ) +
            " found." );
      search = prompt_user( "\nEnter a word to search for: " );
    }    
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Also, please show us your code for load_list() and prompt_user().

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: better to write `search.equals( "quit" )` as `"quit".equals( search )`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String s: list){
    if(s.equals(search)){
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Scanner txtscan = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));

while(txtscan.hasNextLine()){
    String str = txtscan.nextLine();
    if(str.indexOf("word") != -1){
        System.out.println("EXISTS");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code answers this question perfectly:

```
    String word = ""; int val = 0;
    while(!word.matches("quit"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the word to be searched for");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        word = input.next();
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("newFile.txt"));

        while(file.hasNextLine())           
        {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            if(line.indexOf(word) != -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Word EXISTS in the file");
                val = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                val = 0;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(val == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Word does not exist");
        }
        System.out.println("-------continue or quit--- enter continue or quit");
        word = input.next();        
    }
```

Comment: how else would you write the code without using break & continue statements?

Comment: @JimmyBob: Using break improves the code's efficiency as it exits once the word has been found else it would iterate through all the lines.. Just remove the break and continue statements, the code works fine but add this if block after the while loop if(val == 1) System.out.println("Word is found");.

Comment: you could write it as a function and have a return in the if statement instead